# Not able to download chatter desktop

Tags: chatter

I am trying to download chatter desktop but as per the below link

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_desktop_installation.htm

I am not able to find "Desktop Integration" section under setup.

I tried with different org but same case. Also checkd the user and profile permission but nothing came to help.

Any idea how to get this?

Comment: Try searching for Chatter in the Setup search, you can download the application from 'Chatter Desktop Settings' or from 'Chatter Desktop' which is the location that the guide was referring too - before it became out of date..

Comment: @AlexS  I am not able to find any setting for that?

Comment: Just to check - is Chatter enabled? Setup > Chatter > Settings > Chatter Settings - enable should be ticked..When I untick that box the Chatter Desktop link disappears from the Desktop Integration menu.

Answer (score 2):

You should see the below in your setup menu.

[image: Chatter Desktop Install Screenshot]

Alternatively you can access the download link through Desktop Administration > Chatter Desktop Settings.